# How to calculate the average count per hour?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df` and I want to calculate the average number of entries per hour over the year, grouped by runway

```
year   month   day   hour    runway
2017   12      30    10      32L
2017   12      30    11      32L
2017   12      30    11      32L
2017   12      30    11      32L
2017   12      30    11      30R
2018   12      30    10      32L
2018   12      30    10      32L
2018   12      30    11      32L
2018   12      30    11      32L
```

The expected result is this one:

```
year   runway   avg. count per hour
2017   32L      2    
2017   30R      0.5        
2018   32L      2
2018   32L      0
```

I tried this, but it does not calculate the average count per hour:

```
result = df.groupby(['year','runway']).count()
```

Comment: can you explain how is 2 the average count for year 2017, 32L ?

Comment: @YOLO: 32L has 1 entry at 10 and 3 entries at 11 in 2017, right? To get the average number of entries per hour in 2017 for 32L, I did 1+3=4 and divided 4 by 2.

Comment: why did you divide by 2 ?

Comment: @YOLO: Because there are two distinct hours: 10 and 11. I need the average count per hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way of achieving it i.e

```
#Take the count of unique hours per year
s = df.groupby(['year'])['hour'].nunique()
# Take the count of the the runway
n = df.groupby(['year','runway']).size().reset_index()
# Divide them 
n['avg'] = n[0]/n['year'].map(s)

   year runway  0  avg
0  2017    30R  1  0.5
1  2017    32L  4  2.0
2  2018    32L  4  2.0
```